# Ctrl+Click navigate to definition off by a few lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, productivity-power-tools

The ctrl+click navigate to definition functionality in productivity power tools seems to have gone haywire.  It still kind of works, but puts me a few lines away, and occasionally will send me to the definition of some class defined where the cursor actually ends up.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?
Occurs in vs2013 and vs2015.

I also have ReSharper installed and thought there might be some collision happening somewhere, but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Both ReSharper and Productivity Power Tools use Ctrl+Click as Navigate to Definition. Disable that shortcut in one of them.

Comment: I was looking for the option in ReSharper settings, and couldn't find it.  Much easier to just turn it off in Productivity Power Tools.  I wonder why this hasn't been an issue up until the past few days.

Anyway, happy to accept your comment as an answer if you submit it.  As obvious as the solution may have been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ReSharper and Productivity Power Tools use Ctrl+Click as Navigate to Definition. Disable that shortcut in one of them.